# sound problem on lubuntu

Tags: sound, lubuntu

I get no sound whenever I play any music file, but I don't get any error message either. Youtube works properly. Curiously, early in the morning I used Clementine without problem, and now this. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think your sound profile got changed somehow. Execute `pavucontrol` in a terminal. Then change the profile by going to the *configuration* tab. Also check the volumes and muteness. If it is not installed already, install it with `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol` command.

[image]

Comment: Changed profiles but still the same...

Comment: What player is causing this problem?